# Application Loader - An error occurred on the Apple server while trying to authenticate the package

Tags: macos, app-store-connect, application-loader, mac-app-store

The following message comes up on Application Loader while trying to submit a new binary:

> An error occurred on the Apple server while trying to authenticate the package: 411594302.itmsp
>
> An exception has occurred: Error invoking operation:
>
> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis.attachments.AttachmentsImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.axis.attachments.Attachments: Exception trying to invoke operation: validateMetadata
>
> Could not connect to Apple's web service.
>
> Unable to authenticate the package: 411594302.itmsp

I have previously submitted this application to the Mac App Store successfully with the same scripts/settings.

A potential difference I can think of is that I'm now using OS X 10.6.6.

The system log shows more details and a Java exception:

```
[2011-01-08 11:54:07 EST] <main> DBG-X: Using authenticate operation named: validateMetadata
[2011-01-08 11:54:07 EST] <main> DBG-X: Apple's web service operation input parameters:
[2011-01-08 11:54:07 EST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Application = iTMSTransporter
[2011-01-08 11:54:07 EST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Client = Application Loader
[2011-01-08 11:54:07 EST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter ClientVersion = 1.4 (92)
[2011-01-08 11:54:07 EST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Files = [Gravit.pkg, metadata.xml]
[2011-01-08 11:54:07 EST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Host = (null)
[2011-01-08 11:54:07 EST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Metadata = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<package version="software4.5" xmlns="http://apple.com/itunes/importer">
    <software_assets apple_id="411594302">
        <asset type="product-archive">
            <data_file>
                <file_name>Gravit.pkg</file_name>
                <checksum type="md5">7948b5357d8730219fe277e2c145d642</checksum>
                <size>1372906</size>
            </data_file>
        </asset>
    </software_assets>
</package>

[2011-01-08 11:54:07 EST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter MetadataChecksum = dcd612c7eb2258071d0a690f8c3a420a
[2011-01-08 11:54:07 EST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter MetadataCompressed = (suppressed)
[2011-01-08 11:54:07 EST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Mount = (null)
[2011-01-08 11:54:07 EST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter OSIdentifier = Mac OS X 10.6.6 (x86_64); jvm=17.1-b03-307; jre=1.6.0_22-b04-307-10M3261
[2011-01-08 11:54:07 EST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter PackageName = 411594302.itmsp
[2011-01-08 11:54:07 EST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter PackageSize = 1373368
[2011-01-08 11:54:07 EST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Password = **hidden value**
[2011-01-08 11:54:07 EST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Pod = (null)
[2011-01-08 11:54:07 EST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter ProviderName = (null)
[2011-01-08 11:54:07 EST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Transport = Signiant
[2011-01-08 11:54:07 EST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter UploadArguments = -m upload -u email@removed.com -p **hidden value** -f /var/folders/ah/ahoYZjqcEYyNBgIq0+5SGU+++TI/-Tmp-/411594302.itmsp -checksumValidation false -indicator true -v eXtreme -Dtransporter.client=Application Loader -Dtransporter.client.version=1.4 (92)
[2011-01-08 11:54:07 EST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Username = email@removed.com
[2011-01-08 11:54:07 EST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Version = 1.6.5
[2011-01-08 11:54:07 EST] <main> ERROR: An error occurred on the Apple server while trying to authenticate the package: 411594302.itmsp
[2011-01-08 11:54:07 EST] <main> ERROR: An exception has occurred: Error invoking operation:  
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis.attachments.AttachmentsImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.axis.attachments.Attachments: Exception trying to invoke operation: validateMetadata
[2011-01-08 11:54:07 EST] <main> DEBUG: com.webobjects.foundation.NSForwardException for AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}Server.generalException
 faultString: Error invoking operation:  
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis.attachments.AttachmentsImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.axis.attachments.Attachments
 faultActor: null
 faultDetail: 
     stackTrace: AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}Server.generalException
 faultString: Error invoking operation:  
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis.attachments.AttachmentsImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.axis.attachments.Attachments
 faultActor: null
 faultDetail: 

Error invoking operation:  
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis.attachments.AttachmentsImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.axis.attachments.Attachments
     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1329)
     at com.apple.transporter.webobjects.webservices.client.WOWebServiceClient.invoke(WOWebServiceClient.java:498)
     at com.apple.transporter.SOAPService.authenticateOperation(SOAPService.java:273)
     at com.apple.transporter.SOAPService.authenticateOperation(SOAPService.java:164)
     at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload$1.invoke(Upload.java:487)
     at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload$1.invoke(Upload.java:485)
     at com.apple.transporter.SOAPServiceInvoker.invokeWithRetry(SOAPServiceInvoker.java:28)
     at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload.performAuthenticateOperationForUpload(Upload.java:485)
     at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload.performUploadRequestForPackageFile(Upload.java:341)
     at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload.performUploadRequest(Upload.java:211)
     at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload.performUploadRequest(Upload.java:114)
     at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload.execute(Upload.java:1464)
     at com.apple.transporter.Application.begin(Application.java:147)
     at com.apple.transporter.osgi.TransporterService.run(TransporterService.java:46)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
     at com.apple.transporter.osgi.OSGiBootstrapper.runTransporter(OSGiBootstrapper.java:270)
     at com.apple.transporter.osgi.OSGiBootstrapper.bootstrap(OSGiBootstrapper.java:197)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
     at com.apple.transporter.FrameworkLoader.start(FrameworkLoader.java:98)
     at com.apple.transporter.Application.main(Application.java:71)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
     at com.webobjects._bootstrap.WOBootstrap.main(WOBootstrap.java:71)

Error invoking operation:  
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis.attachments.AttachmentsImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.axis.attachments.Attachments
     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1329)
     at com.apple.transporter.webobjects.webservices.client.WOWebServiceClient.invoke(WOWebServiceClient.java:498)
     at com.apple.transporter.SOAPService.authenticateOperation(SOAPService.java:273)
     at com.apple.transporter.SOAPService.authenticateOperation(SOAPService.java:164)
     at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload$1.invoke(Upload.java:487)
     at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload$1.invoke(Upload.java:485)
     at com.apple.transporter.SOAPServiceInvoker.invokeWithRetry(SOAPServiceInvoker.java:28)
     at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload.performAuthenticateOperationForUpload(Upload.java:485)
     at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload.performUploadRequestForPackageFile(Upload.java:341)
     at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload.performUploadRequest(Upload.java:211)
     at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload.performUploadRequest(Upload.java:114)
     at com.apple.transporter.operation.Upload.execute(Upload.java:1464)
     at com.apple.transporter.Application.begin(Application.java:147)
     at com.apple.transporter.osgi.TransporterService.run(TransporterService.java:46)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
     at com.apple.transporter.osgi.OSGiBootstrapper.runTransporter(OSGiBootstrapper.java:270)
     at com.apple.transporter.osgi.OSGiBootstrapper.bootstrap(OSGiBootstrapper.java:197)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
     at com.apple.transporter.FrameworkLoader.start(FrameworkLoader.java:98)
     at com.apple.transporter.Application.main(Application.java:71)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
     at com.webobjects._bootstrap.WOBootstrap.main(WOBootstrap.java:71)

[2011-01-08 11:54:07 EST] <main> ERROR: Could not connect to Apple's web service.
[2011-01-08 11:54:07 EST] <main> ERROR: Unable to authenticate the package: 411594302.itmsp
[2011-01-08 11:54:07 EST] <main>  INFO: Done performing authentication.
[2011-01-08 11:54:07 EST] <main> DBG-X: Returning 1
Jan  8 11:54:07 raptop Application Loader[25059]:  Out:

Package Summary:
 
1 package(s) were not uploaded because they had problems:
     /var/folders/ah/ahoYZjqcEYyNBgIq0+5SGU+++TI/-Tmp-/411594302.itmsp - Error Messages:
          An error occurred on the Apple server while trying to authenticate the package: 411594302.itmsp
          An exception has occurred: Error invoking operation:  
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis.attachments.AttachmentsImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.axis.attachments.Attachments: Exception trying to invoke operation: validateMetadata
          Could not connect to Apple's web service.
          Unable to authenticate the package: 411594302.itmsp
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the latest Xcode?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. 10.6.6, Xcode 3.2.5, same certificates and build process as I had back in December when this worked... What the HELL???

Comment: I thought I was the only one!

Comment: Same issue here, could it be a server availability issue on Apple's side?

Comment: I'm also running into the same problem. Really awesome with clients wondering why it's not submitted yet! Will try with App Loader on non Xcode machine.

Comment: Maybe you should consider acknowledging one of the several answers that have been posted.  I wasted a hefty bounty as a result.

Comment: @Greg: Will only accept when there is an actual fix for the problem. Answers such as "use another computer" is not a fix.

Answer (score 4):

Same sort of workaround but I loaded an old version of AppLoader (from a link in the UsingApplicationLoader.pdf - http://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_
1.3.dmg) onto a mac with NO Xcode and it worked fine when my dev' machine with Xcode 3.2.5 and AppLoader 1.4(92) showed the same error as above. I have made no restores or anything special since Decemember (apart from Xcode update).

Comment: I just followed this, and it worked. Downloaded AppLoader onto another mac (no xcode) and was able to upload without a problem. Has anyone reported this to Apple?

Comment: I just uninstalled xcode and installed the v1.3 Application Loader, but it still not working. Any idea about how to upload the app (I don't have any mac that has not xcode)?

Comment: I downloaded v1.3 from this link onto a mac _with_ Xcode & v1.4.1 installed. I didn't uninstall anything.
The v1.3 Application Loader worked, for the first time in 5-6 days.

Answer (score 3):

Managed to resolve this issue by installing the command line tools from Xcode 4.4 and then trying again.

I first installed the command line tools from Xcode 4.5 beta and it seems the Application Loader, as well as Xcode use the last-installed command line tools.  So if you installed a beta in combination with the command line tools, the official Xcode will still use the beta command-line tools which will result in failing to upload a binary.

Conclusion: install the latest official command line tools (through Xcode > Preferences > Downloads > Components > Command Line Tools and try again.

Comment: This was the first and only solution I tried and it worked.  I also had to restart xcode.  I am using xcode 4.6.2.  I believe that the problem started after I upgraded to an SSD using Carbon Copy Cloner.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the "right" answer, but it's a working answer ... I successfully overcame this issue under the following circumstances...

Built and Archived my app as usual on my MacBook Pro, with XCode 3.2.5.
Saved that archive (in the Organizer utility) to my Desktop
Copied that archive to my Mac Mini that has XCode 3.2.4 installed.
On the Mac Mini, I used the Application Loader (Version 1.3.1) to successfully submit the archive.

I don't know what changed or what's wrong with the 3.2.5 installation on my MacBook, I'm currently downloading a fresh dmg to reinstall that, but at the very least, the slightly older Application Loader on a different machine worked fine.

Comment: I believe the answer of why this is the case lies with the fact that I've done a restore from a backup since December. I think something got jacked in permissions, even though fixing them didn't fix them. Anyone else do a restore from a bad drive or machine swap?

Comment: Contacting iTunesConnect Support, they've indicated that "they're looking into the issue."

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Greg Comb's experience above, I've managed to upload the exactly same archive using the same version of Application Loader but on a different machine??

In case anyone else is wondering the same error occurs if you try and submit it via Organiser.

[edit to say AppLoader version on both machines is 1.4 (92)]